# Programmatically send an HttpRequestMessage to the Web API pipeline without Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I was wondering if there was a way to manually craft an HTTPRequestMessage object and programmatically "send" it to Web API pipeline without actually having the Web API project hosted somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a **HttpServer**  and then pass it to **HttpClient** constructor. Please see the code snippet below:

```
            HttpConfiguration configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
            configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );


            var server = new HttpServer(configuration);

            var client = new HttpClient(server);

            Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = client.GetAsync("http://www.whatever/yourcontroller");
```

Answer (score 2):

In-memory testing described in the below post is an example of how you could achieve this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/05/06/in-memory-client-amp-host-and-integration-testing-of-your-web-api-service.aspx

Note that this is an old post but most of the concepts are still relevant.

Comment: Both answers look valid, I went with the other because it was quicker.